# Android studio - preview when editing text has disappered

Tags: android-studio

When I first started using AS I really liked the edit layout feature. I like the way it shows you a preview on the right of the screen when you are editing the XML.

This seems to have disappeared - how do I turn it back on? It's not a show stopper, but it was a nice feature.

The previewer is way better than the clunky Eclipse one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a tab called "Preview" on the right side of the screen. 
[image]

If you can't see this then click the little square on the bottom left of the screen and it will appear. 
[image]

Comment: Thanks - that'll teach me for turning off all of the pinning.